# positioning edit-form Popup for telerik mvc grid

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, popup, telerik, edit

Can anybody tell me if there is a way to position the edit-form Popup for an mvc grid to align to the center of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend found out the easiest way of doing by using one of the unexposed inbuilt function of telerik grid

```
        var popup = $("#" + e.currentTarget.id + "PopUp");
        //get the data window contained by the popup
        var popupDataWin = popup.data("tWindow");

        //change popup title by calling the title 
        popupDataWin.title("Custom Title");            
        //center the window by calling the method center
        popupDataWin.center();
```

put this piece of code in client side on_edit api of the grid and you will see the magic

Comment: Could you add a little more context to your example? Where on the client do you add this?

Comment: this piece of code should be placed within the client side OnEdit API of the telerik grid  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientsideevents. Most of the pop-up issues were reseolved in new version of terik, so probably this issue is resolved too..

Answer (score 3):

thanks guys for the valid answers. I know we can position a custom popup window but not for built in edit mode windows.

> However I manipulated the position
>   with jquery on the client side on_edit
>   API of telerik grid.

```
var popup = $("#" + e.currentTarget.id + "PopUp");

 popup.css({ "left": ($(window).width()/2 - $(popup).width()/2) + "px", "top": ($(window).height()/2 - $(popup).height()/2) + "px" });
```

e.currentTarget.id gives the gridname.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this can be done automatically with configuration option - now on the live demos the popup gets centered in the grid. My wild guess is that you can position it in the center of the screen with javascript...

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before using a custom popup using a separately defined Telerik Mvc Window.  My sample code looked like this:

```
   <%= Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("CompanyWindow")
    .Title("Company Details")
    .Buttons(b => b.Maximize().Close())
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Width(600)
    .Height(600)
    .Draggable(true) 
    .Resizable()
%>

<% Html.Telerik().Grid<Vigilaris.Booking.Services.CompanySummaryDTO>()
   .Name("CompaniesGrid")
   .ToolBar(tb => tb.Template(() => { %>
       <a href ="#" onclick="createCompany()" >Insert</a>
       <% }))
   .Columns(col =>
       {
           col.Bound(c => c.Id).Width(20);
           col.Bound(c => c.CompanyName).Width(120);
           col.Bound(c => c.ResponsiblePersonFullName).Width(160);
           col.Bound(c => c.ResponsiblePersonUserName).Width(160);
           col.Bound(c => c.ResponsiblePersonEmail).Width(160);
           col.Command(cmd =>
               {
                   cmd.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image);
               }).Title("Edit");
       })
   .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))
   .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax()
       .Select("_IndexAjax", "Company")
       .Insert("_InsertAjax", "Company")
       .Update("_UpdateAjax", "Company")
   )
   .Sortable()
   .Render();
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function createCompany() {
        var url = '<%= Url.Action("New", "Company") %>'
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            var window = $('#CompanyWindow').data('tWindow');
            window.content(data);
            window.center().open();
        });
    }
</script>
```

You will notice in the createCompany function that I call window.center().open().  This explicitly centres the popup.

However, I don't think this is exactly what you want to do, but it may give you some pointers in the right direction. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid()
.Name("FormFildGrid")
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnEdit("Grid_onEdit"))
```

)

```
function Grid_onEdit(e) {
    var popup = $("#" + e.currentTarget.id + "PopUp");
    var popupDataWin = popup.data("tWindow");
    var l = ($(window).width() / 2 - $(popup).width() / 2);
    popup.css({ "left": l + "px", "margin-left": "0", "width": $(popup).width() });
}
```